# PROGRAM HAS RETURNED CONTROL TO THE OPERATING SYSTEM in emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

So I'm trying to get this code (8 bit Division) to work but it just returns the line "PROGRAM HAS RETURNED CONTROL TO THE OPERATING SYSTEM". Need help on what am I actually doing wrong.

```
DATA SEGMENT
NUM1 DB -10
NUM2 DB 02
QUO DB 1 DUP(0)
REM DB 1 DUP(0)
DATA ENDS
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
START: MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX
MOV AL,NUM1 
CBW
IDIV NUM2 
MOV QUO,AL 
MOV REM,AH 
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Thank you!

Comment: What else did you expect it to do? You're doing some calculations, but there's no code to display any of the results.

Comment: Can you please help me to add a line that can display results?

Comment: That's not something you can do in one line. You'll have to convert the value you want to use into a string, and then use an interrupt to print that string. Plenty of questions have already been asked on how to print integers in DOS assembly programs. Do some searching.